# Azure DW storage location

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-synapse

[Azure SQL Data Warehouse documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/massively-parallel-processing-mpp-architecture) says:
SQL Data Warehouse uses Azure storage to keep your user data safe. Since your data is stored and managed by Azure storage, SQL Data Warehouse charges separately for your storage consumption.

I am not clear which type of Azure Storage DW is using. For example, Blob store, File Store or Table Store etc.,

1) Is this storage within my account or Azure account?
2) Can we access this storage outside of DW? Example through REST API or Via Storage Explorer etc.,

If above 2 options are possible,
3) If I copy this blog or file to some other account and restore to DW?

Couldn't find this technical implementation details anywhere on Azure documentation. Appreciate any inputs.

Comment: DW is table storage. Looking at the Azure API reference it looks like only "user activities" are available via the API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/datawarehouseuseractivities/get This is a fully managed service so you don't have access to the storage itself. Same for restores. These are managed via snapshots in Azure https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/backup-and-restore.

Comment: @Rthomas529 "This is a fully managed service so you don't have access to the storage itself." make sense. Thanks!